# What more context can you provide about a one-liner macro?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

The question about *[NOT macro: is this bad practice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192000/not-macro-is-this-bad-practice)* has been closed for not providing concrete context. But what else could OP have written to make it on-topic? OP also explained why he likes this solution.

I find he did everything right. The macro is a one-liner with a usage example.

Comment: Related discussion: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1583/31503

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree, there have always been discussions about 1-liner questions, and I feel the specific question here has been closed because the closers saw the "use case" as being example code, but it's just a test-case, not the code under review itself.

I've been discussing the question in the 2nd monitor, and I believe it should be reopened when it clearly separates the code under review from the example use-cases of the code.

Comment: And now I have reopened it.

Answer (score 5):

I'm one of those who close-voted the *initial* version of the question. My *personal* reason was that the macro was embedded in example code around a hypothetical scenario and example. What's under review? The example? The macro? It might be the macro definition or the macro usage, or both.

I [initially asked in the 2nd monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43994513#43994513) whether it's on-topic and then got pulled into closing by the "close(2)" vortex, although I already had my answer ready. Additionally, I accidentally misread OPs additional question as "what are the best practices", which is a section in [dont-ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Immediately after my vote I thought about alternative formulations that would make it on-topic and [edited it](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/192000/2) after I got [the author's OK](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192000/a-not-macro-for-negative-conditions#comment368671_192000).

So to answer your original question: you cannot do much, to be honest, except make it clear that your one-liner is under review and add several examples.